# don't use scrolloff=5 for mouse clicks in (neo)vim

Tags: vim, ide, editor, neovim

I use (neo)vim with `mouse=a` and `scrolloff=5`. Clicking on one of the top or bottom five lines with the mouse causes the screen to jump (so that the new cursor position is more centered), which distracts me. Is there any way to disable "`so=5`" for mouse-clicking only?

I use (neo)vim in different terminal emulators on linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the `scrolloff` value using a click mapping, refer `:help <LeftMouse>` However, you'll have to re-enable the scroll setting afterwards as re-enabling the setting in the mapping would again cause the view to jump up/down.

This will disable the `scrolloff` setting and the view will remain unchanged:

```
nnoremap <LeftMouse> :let &so=0<cr><LeftMouse>
```

With the above, the view will not jump, but you'll have to re-enable `so`

We could re-enable it in the same mapping, but that would mean, you'll see the same behavior of view jumping up or down as `so` is applied immediately after it's set.

```
nnoremap <LeftMouse> :let temp=&so<cr>:let &so=0<cr><LeftMouse>:let &so=temp<cr>
```

So, there isn't an ideal solution to what yo want (at least I know of). You could either disable `so` completely and use something like `zz` or get used to the behavior of `so` on mouse click.

Comment: Do you know if there would be way to re-set `scrolloff` at the next cursor movement in vertical direction?